# Why does spaCy not preserve intra-word-hyphens during tokenization like Stanford CoreNLP does?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

SpaCy Version: 2.0.11

Python Version: 3.6.5

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

My Sentence Samples:

`Marketing-Representative- won't die in car accident.`

or

`Out-of-box implementation`

Expected Tokens:

`["Marketing-Representative", "-", "wo", "n't", "die", "in", "car", "accident", "."]`

`["Out-of-box", "implementation"]`

SpaCy Tokens(Default Tokenizer):

`["Marketing", "-", "Representative-", "wo", "n't", "die", "in", "car", "accident", "."]`

`["Out", "-", "of", "-", "box", "implementation"]`

I tried creating custom tokenizer but it won't handle all edge cases as handled by spaCy using tokenizer_exceptions(Code below):

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
from spacy.util import compile_prefix_regex, compile_infix_regex, compile_suffix_regex
import re
nlp = spacy.load('en')
prefix_re = compile_prefix_regex(nlp.Defaults.prefixes)
suffix_re = compile_suffix_regex(nlp.Defaults.suffixes)
infix_re = re.compile(r'''[.\,\?\:\;\...\‘\’\`\“\”\"\'~]''')

def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, prefix_search=prefix_re.search,
                                suffix_search=suffix_re.search,
                                infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer,
                                token_match=None)
nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)
doc = nlp("Marketing-Representative- won't die in car accident.")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text)
```

Output:

```
Marketing-Representative-
won
'
t
die
in
car
accident
.
```

I need someone to guide me towards the appropriate way of doing this.

Either making changes in the regex above could do it or any other method or I even tried spaCy's Rule-Based Matcher but wasn't able to create rule to handle hyphens between more than 2 words e.g. "out-of-box" so that a Matcher can be created to be used with span.merge().

Either way I need to have words containing intra-word-hyphens to become single token as handled by Stanford CoreNLP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not documented at `spacey` [usage site](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-tokenization) ,

It looks like that we just need to add `regex` for *fix we are working with, in this case infix.

Also, it appears we can extend `nlp.Defaults.prefixes` with custom `regex`

```
infixes = nlp.Defaults.prefixes + (r"[./]", r"[-]~", r"(.'.)")
```

This will give you desired result. There is no need set default to `prefix` and `suffix` since we are not working with those.

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
from spacy.util import compile_prefix_regex, compile_infix_regex, compile_suffix_regex
import re

nlp = spacy.load('en')

infixes = nlp.Defaults.prefixes + (r"[./]", r"[-]~", r"(.'.)")

infix_re = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes)

def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer)

nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)

s1 = "Marketing-Representative- won't die in car accident."
s2 = "Out-of-box implementation"

for s in s1,s2:
    doc = nlp("{}".format(s))
    print([token.text for token in doc])
```

Result

```
$python3 /tmp/nlp.py  
['Marketing-Representative-', 'wo', "n't", 'die', 'in', 'car', 'accident', '.']  
['Out-of-box', 'implementation']
```

You may want to fix addon regex to make it more robust for other kind of tokens that are close to the applied regex.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your solution works well although still i'm not able to fix the trailing hyphen from the token("Marketing-Representative-") generated by custom tokenizer. I'm working on it though.

Comment: Why do the following; infixes = nlp.Defaults.prefixes + (r"[./]", r"[-]~", r"(.'.)")

Comment: And not just the following; infixes = nlp.Defaults.prefixes + (r"[-]~")?

Comment: What are the first and the last patterns for in infixes = nlp.Defaults.prefixes + (r"[./]", r"[-]~", r"(.'.)")?

Answer (score 0):

I am also wanting to modify spaCy's tokenizer to more closely match the semantics of CoreNLP. Pasted below is what I came up with, that addresses the hyphens issue in this thread (including the trailing hypens) and some additional fixes. I had to copy the default infix expressions and make modifications to them, but was able to simply append a new suffix expression:

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.char_classes import ALPHA, ALPHA_LOWER, ALPHA_UPPER
from spacy.lang.char_classes import CONCAT_QUOTES, LIST_ELLIPSES, LIST_ICONS

def initializeTokenizer(nlp):

    prefixes = nlp.Defaults.prefixes 
    
    infixes = (
        LIST_ELLIPSES
        + LIST_ICONS
        + [
            r'(?<=[0-9])[+\-\*^](?=[0-9-])',
            r'(?<=[{al}{q}])\.(?=[{au}{q}])'.format(
                al=ALPHA_LOWER, au=ALPHA_UPPER, q=CONCAT_QUOTES
            ),
            # REMOVE: commented out regex that splits on hyphens between letters:
            #r"(?<=[{a}])(?:{h})(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA, h=HYPHENS),
            # EDIT: remove split on slash between letters, and add comma
            #r'(?<=[{a}0-9])[:<>=/](?=[{a}])'.format(a=ALPHA),
            r'(?<=[{a}0-9])[:<>=,](?=[{a}])'.format(a=ALPHA),
            # ADD: ampersand as an infix character except for dual upper FOO&FOO variant
            r'(?<=[{a}0-9])[&](?=[{al}0-9])'.format(a=ALPHA, al=ALPHA_LOWER),
            r'(?<=[{al}0-9])[&](?=[{a}0-9])'.format(a=ALPHA, al=ALPHA_LOWER),
        ]
    )

    # ADD: add suffix to split on trailing hyphen
    custom_suffixes = [r'[-]']
    suffixes = nlp.Defaults.suffixes
    suffixes = tuple(list(suffixes) + custom_suffixes)

    infix_re = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes)
    suffix_re = spacy.util.compile_suffix_regex(suffixes)

    nlp.tokenizer.suffix_search = suffix_re.search
    nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = infix_re.finditer
```