# SpaCy -- intra-word hyphens. How to treat them one word?

Tags: nlp, tokenize, spacy

Following is the code provided as answer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293874/why-does-spacy-not-preserve-intra-word-hyphens-during-tokenization-like-stanford/52380286#comment97213137_52380286);

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
from spacy.util import compile_prefix_regex, compile_infix_regex, compile_suffix_regex
import re

nlp = spacy.load('en')

infixes = nlp.Defaults.prefixes + (r"[./]", r"[-]~", r"(.'.)")

infix_re = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes)

def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer)

nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)

s1 = "Marketing-Representative- won't die in car accident."
s2 = "Out-of-box implementation"

for s in s1,s2:
    doc = nlp("{}".format(s))
    print([token.text for token in doc])
```

Result

```
$python3 /tmp/nlp.py  
['Marketing-Representative-', 'wo', "n't", 'die', 'in', 'car', 'accident', '.']  
['Out-of-box', 'implementation']
```

What are the first (r"[./]") and the last (r"(.'.)") patterns used for in the following?

```
infixes = nlp.Defaults.prefixes + (r"[./]", r"[-]~", r"(.'.)")
```

Edit: I expect the splits to be as follows;

That

is

Yahya

's

laptop-cover

.

---

I want spacy to treat intra-hyphen word as one token without impacting negatively on other split rules.

"That is Yahya's laptop-cover. 3.14!"

["That", "is", "Yahya", "'s", "laptop-cover", ".", "3.14", "!"] (***EXPECTED***)

By default,

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
for token in nlp("That is Yahya's laptop-cover. 3.14!"):
    print (token.text)
```

SpaCy gives;

```
["That", "is", "Yahya", "'s", "laptop", "-", "cover", ".", "3.14", "!"]
```

However,

```
from spacy.util import compile_infix_regex
infixes = nlp.Defaults.prefixes + tuple([r"[-]~"])
infix_re = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes)
nlp.tokenizer = spacy.tokenizer.Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer)
for token in nlp("That is Yahya's laptop-cover. 3.14!"):
    print (token.text)
```

gives;

```
["That", "is", "Yahya", "'", "s", "laptop-cover.", "3.14", "!"]
```

Comment: I think all you need to know is [explained here](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizers).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That link doesn't help, I had already gone through it. 'infixes' is being assigned all the nlp.Defaults.prefixes plus the following three patterns (r"[./]", r"[-]~", r"(.'.)"). The middle one is clearly for including HYPH such that intra-word hyphens are not tagged separately, what are the other two patterns used for?

Comment: Please paste your code as text, not as an image. Then, add the exact requirements, move all your comments under my questions that pertain to the actual problem to the *question*. Then, we'll see what can be done. It starts looking like  a new question already.

Comment: The actual question was only regarding patterns in (r"[./]", r"[-]~", r"(.'.)") which you answered quite well. Latter, I found that by updating Infixes I got other problems emerging like "boy's" -> ("bo", "y's"). I wish I could ask another separate question which I can't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ***NOTE***: To see the custom tokenizer that keeps the hyphenated words see the botton of the answer.

Here, a custom tokenizer is defined, that tokenizes text into tokens using a set of built-in (`nlp.Defaults.prefixes`) and custom (`[./]`, `[-]~`, `(.'.)`) patterns.

The `nlp.Defaults.prefixes + (r"[./]", r"[-]~", r"(.'.)")` is  tuple concatenation operation, the result looks like

```
('§', '%', '=', '—', '–', '\\+(?![0-9])', '…', '……', ',', ':', ';', '\\!', '\\?', '¿', '؟', '¡', '\\(', '\\)', '\\[', '\\]', '\\{', '\\}', '<', '>', '_', '#', '\\*', '&', '。', '？', '！', '，', '、', '；', '：', '～', '·', '।', '،', '؛', '٪', '\\.\\.+', '…', "\\'", '"', '”', '“', '`', '‘', '´', '’', '‚', ',', '„', '»', '«', '「', '」', '『', '』', '（', '）', '〔', '〕', '【', '】', '《', '》', '〈', '〉', '\\$', '£', '€', '¥', '฿', 'US\\$', 'C\\$', 'A\\$', '₽', '﷼', '₴', '[\\u00A6\\u00A9\\u00AE\\u00B0\\u0482\\u058D\\u058E\\u060E\\u060F\\u06DE\\u06E9\\u06FD\\u06FE\\u07F6\\u09FA\\u0B70\\u0BF3-\\u0BF8\\u0BFA\\u0C7F\\u0D4F\\u0D79\\u0F01-\\u0F03\\u0F13\\u0F15-\\u0F17\\u0F1A-\\u0F1F\\u0F34\\u0F36\\u0F38\\u0FBE-\\u0FC5\\u0FC7-\\u0FCC\\u0FCE\\u0FCF\\u0FD5-\\u0FD8\\u109E\\u109F\\u1390-\\u1399\\u1940\\u19DE-\\u19FF\\u1B61-\\u1B6A\\u1B74-\\u1B7C\\u2100\\u2101\\u2103-\\u2106\\u2108\\u2109\\u2114\\u2116\\u2117\\u211E-\\u2123\\u2125\\u2127\\u2129\\u212E\\u213A\\u213B\\u214A\\u214C\\u214D\\u214F\\u218A\\u218B\\u2195-\\u2199\\u219C-\\u219F\\u21A1\\u21A2\\u21A4\\u21A5\\u21A7-\\u21AD\\u21AF-\\u21CD\\u21D0\\u21D1\\u21D3\\u21D5-\\u21F3\\u2300-\\u2307\\u230C-\\u231F\\u2322-\\u2328\\u232B-\\u237B\\u237D-\\u239A\\u23B4-\\u23DB\\u23E2-\\u2426\\u2440-\\u244A\\u249C-\\u24E9\\u2500-\\u25B6\\u25B8-\\u25C0\\u25C2-\\u25F7\\u2600-\\u266E\\u2670-\\u2767\\u2794-\\u27BF\\u2800-\\u28FF\\u2B00-\\u2B2F\\u2B45\\u2B46\\u2B4D-\\u2B73\\u2B76-\\u2B95\\u2B98-\\u2BC8\\u2BCA-\\u2BFE\\u2CE5-\\u2CEA\\u2E80-\\u2E99\\u2E9B-\\u2EF3\\u2F00-\\u2FD5\\u2FF0-\\u2FFB\\u3004\\u3012\\u3013\\u3020\\u3036\\u3037\\u303E\\u303F\\u3190\\u3191\\u3196-\\u319F\\u31C0-\\u31E3\\u3200-\\u321E\\u322A-\\u3247\\u3250\\u3260-\\u327F\\u328A-\\u32B0\\u32C0-\\u32FE\\u3300-\\u33FF\\u4DC0-\\u4DFF\\uA490-\\uA4C6\\uA828-\\uA82B\\uA836\\uA837\\uA839\\uAA77-\\uAA79\\uFDFD\\uFFE4\\uFFE8\\uFFED\\uFFEE\\uFFFC\\uFFFD\\U00010137-\\U0001013F\\U00010179-\\U00010189\\U0001018C-\\U0001018E\\U00010190-\\U0001019B\\U000101A0\\U000101D0-\\U000101FC\\U00010877\\U00010878\\U00010AC8\\U0001173F\\U00016B3C-\\U00016B3F\\U00016B45\\U0001BC9C\\U0001D000-\\U0001D0F5\\U0001D100-\\U0001D126\\U0001D129-\\U0001D164\\U0001D16A-\\U0001D16C\\U0001D183\\U0001D184\\U0001D18C-\\U0001D1A9\\U0001D1AE-\\U0001D1E8\\U0001D200-\\U0001D241\\U0001D245\\U0001D300-\\U0001D356\\U0001D800-\\U0001D9FF\\U0001DA37-\\U0001DA3A\\U0001DA6D-\\U0001DA74\\U0001DA76-\\U0001DA83\\U0001DA85\\U0001DA86\\U0001ECAC\\U0001F000-\\U0001F02B\\U0001F030-\\U0001F093\\U0001F0A0-\\U0001F0AE\\U0001F0B1-\\U0001F0BF\\U0001F0C1-\\U0001F0CF\\U0001F0D1-\\U0001F0F5\\U0001F110-\\U0001F16B\\U0001F170-\\U0001F1AC\\U0001F1E6-\\U0001F202\\U0001F210-\\U0001F23B\\U0001F240-\\U0001F248\\U0001F250\\U0001F251\\U0001F260-\\U0001F265\\U0001F300-\\U0001F3FA\\U0001F400-\\U0001F6D4\\U0001F6E0-\\U0001F6EC\\U0001F6F0-\\U0001F6F9\\U0001F700-\\U0001F773\\U0001F780-\\U0001F7D8\\U0001F800-\\U0001F80B\\U0001F810-\\U0001F847\\U0001F850-\\U0001F859\\U0001F860-\\U0001F887\\U0001F890-\\U0001F8AD\\U0001F900-\\U0001F90B\\U0001F910-\\U0001F93E\\U0001F940-\\U0001F970\\U0001F973-\\U0001F976\\U0001F97A\\U0001F97C-\\U0001F9A2\\U0001F9B0-\\U0001F9B9\\U0001F9C0-\\U0001F9C2\\U0001F9D0-\\U0001F9FF\\U0001FA60-\\U0001FA6D]', '[/.]', '-~', "(.'.)")
```

As you see, these are all regular expressions and are used to process in-word punctuation, infixes. See the [Spacy tokenizer algorithm](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#how-tokenizer-works):

> The algorithm can be summarized as follows:
>
> 1. Iterate over space-separated substrings
> 2. Check whether we have an explicitly defined rule for this substring. If we do, use it.
> 3. Otherwise, try to consume a prefix.
> 4. If we consumed a prefix, go back to the beginning of the loop, so that special-cases always get priority.
> 5. If we didn’t consume a prefix, try to consume a suffix.
> 6. **If we can’t consume a prefix or suffix, look for “infixes” — stuff like hyphens etc.**
> 7. Once we can’t consume any more of the string, handle it as a single token.

Now, when we are at infix handling step, these regular expressions are used to split text into tokens based also on these patterns.

E.g. `[/.]` is important because if you do not add it, `abc.def/ghi` will be a single token, but with the pattern added, it will be split into `'abc', '.', 'def', '/', 'ghi'`.

The `[-]~` (that is the same as `-~`) matches a `-` and wants to match `~` right after, but since it is not there, the `-` is skipped and no split occurs, you get the whole `'Marketing-Representative-'` token. Note, however, if you have `'Marketing-~Representative-'`  in the sentence, and you use `-~` regex you will get `['Marketing', '-~', 'Representative-']` as a result as there will be a match.

The  `.'.` regex matches any char + `'`  + any char. A dot matches any char in regex. So, the rule just tokenizes (splits out) these tokens out of the sentence (e.g. `n't`, r'd, etc.)

**Answer to edit**

You should be very careful when adding new rules and check if they do not overlap with already added ones.

E.g. when you add `r"\b's\b"` to split out Genetive case apostrophe-s, you should  "override" the `"\\'"` rule from `nlp.Defaults.prefixes`. Either remove it if you do not plan to match `'` as infix, or give priority to your custom rules by appendng the `nlp.Defaults.prefixes` to those rules, not vice versa.

See a sample code:

```
import re
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
infixes = tuple([r"'s\b", r"(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)"]) +  nlp.Defaults.prefixes
infix_re = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes)

def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer)

nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)
doc = nlp(u"That is Yahya's laptop-cover. 3.14!")
print([t.text for t in doc])
```

Output: `['That', 'is', 'Yahya', "'s", 'laptop-cover', '.', '3.14', '!']`

**Details**

- `r"'s\b"` - matches `'s` that are followed with a word boundary
- `r"(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)` - matches a `.` that is not preceded or followed with a digit.

And **if you want to use a custom tokenizer that keeps hyphenated letter words** as single tokens you will have to re-define the [`infixes`](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/58533f01bf926546337ad2868abe7fc8f0a3b3ae/spacy/lang/punctuation.py#L36): the `r"(?<=[{a}])(?:{h})(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA, h=HYPHENS),` line accounts for that and you need to get rid of it. Since it is the only item that contains a `-|–|—|--|---|——|~` string it will be easier to drop this item from the `infixes` and re-compile the infix pattern:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
from spacy.util import compile_infix_regex

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

inf = list(nlp.Defaults.infixes)
inf = [x for x in inf if '-|–|—|--|---|——|~' not in x] # remove the hyphen-between-letters pattern from infix patterns
infix_re = compile_infix_regex(tuple(inf))

def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, prefix_search=nlp.tokenizer.prefix_search,
                                suffix_search=nlp.tokenizer.suffix_search,
                                infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer,
                                token_match=nlp.tokenizer.token_match,
                                rules=nlp.Defaults.tokenizer_exceptions)

nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)
doc = nlp("That is Yahya's laptop-cover. 3.14!")
print([t.text for t in doc])
# => ['That', 'is', 'Yahya', "'s", 'laptop-cover', '.', '3.14', '!']
```

Comment: r"'s\b" stopped only "'s" to be split as ("'", "s"). However, cases like "They'll" were being split incorrectly as ("They", "'", "ll"). Therefore, I modified the pattern as r"'\w{1,2}\b" which solves the issue. ^^ I wish I dont get more similar issues. You see intra-hyphen issue gets solved but as a result many other issue arise.

Comment: Further r"n?'\w{1,2}\b" makes sure that "aren't" is not split into ("aren", "'t")

Comment: @ZeeshanAli Why do you keep the `"\\'"` rule then? Remove it if you do not want to split against `'`.

Comment: If I remove it, "'s" gets split as ("'", "s") :( I need SpaCy to treat intra-hyphen words as one word, and keep all the other split rules as it is.

Comment: No idea how you do that, `infixes = tuple([r"(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)"]) +  tuple(x for x in nlp.Defaults.prefixes if x != "\\'")` yields - I guess - expected result.

Comment: @ZeeshanAli Sorry, I can't follow you. Once you say you want `They'll`, next time you say it is not expected. Please feel free to modify the rules, use only the ones you want.

Comment: I want SpaCy to split text as it already does except when there is an intra-hyphen word. It by default splits '''They'll''', which is great. I'd like it be the way it is.